# Specifying Android library version code/name

Tags: android, android-library, android-version

Which is the right place to specify android's library project version code/name? Whats the current state on a library's Android Manifest? When you bundle a library jar, can AndroidManifest be ignored while bundling jar and still delivering a usable/unbroken jar?

My question is related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853639/retrieve-androidversionname-from-library-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set version code/ name of a project in its [`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). But if it's a library project, all information in the manifest will be ignored after integrating into the host project.

There is [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25226).

Comment: wondering whats the best way at this time to version a library?

Answer (score 1):

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```

Just make sure that you import the BuildConfig for your library (as literally every android library/app has it's own BuildConfig on it's package path). The Android Studio's Gradle Build system indicates that this is always generated as of version 0.7.0 (see [changelog](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)). This persists as a generated class into the hosting app/library.